# Using salvage power supply, RM1-3490 HP Laserjet

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, wiring

EDIT: What do I need to do, to hot wire the board to fully turn on?

I have a salvage powersupply from a big printer/copier and have a upcoming project and I'd like to use it.

Problem is I cannot make it power up properly.
I think main power from plug with red and black wires will give me 24v. And by the looks of it it packs quite a punch.

I have made this pinout by tracing the plugs:

```
>Plug1, main power output?!

>Plug 2

1 - 5v
2 - 5v
3 - GND
4 - 3,5v
5 - GND
6 - Relay, short to ground to close
7 - Opto pin 4, collector, part Q201 next to black relay
8 - NPN base, part pc100 next to green transformer
9 - GND
10 - nc
11 - nc

>Plug 3

Brown - 5v
Yellow -  3,3v
Blue - GND
```

[image]

Comment: please post a clear picture of the connectors at the other end of the cables

Comment: what model printer did that come from? ... it may be possible to find a service manual

Comment: It is one of those giant copy/printer machines. Have scrolled trough som manuals but cannot find the info I need.

Comment: The plugs are as described in the pinout, the multi wired plug all wires are purple.

Comment: Sorry for multiple comments, Me and the ios app are not friends yet. I think the opto is signaling the NPN tranny, I will try with a loaf aswell tonight. Probably one of those wires need to sense the output voltage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To power up the board's 24v rail I shorted the NPN tranny and relay to ground.

As per rating on the output diodes, [FCH30B10](http://pdf.dzsc.com/FCH/FCH30B10_1215111.pdf), and the switching FET, [2SK3568](https://www.mouser.es/datasheet/2/408/DST_2SK3568-TDE_EN_10785-479924.pdf), the 24 rail can output a wooping 30A continuously.

Only question remain is the function of the opto next to the relay. The placement suggest it is sensing current on the primary side maybe?!
Pin 7 on the multiple wire plug is the collector of the opto...

To power on:

```
Plug with purple wires

Pin 8 to GND
Pin 6 to GND
```